Is there a way to see git history by the date changes were merged to a branch?
Is there a way to see git history by the date changes were merged to a branch?
A typical git history shows changes based on when the change was made rather than when it was merged.  Below is a typical example where a change merged recently is lower in the history because the original change is older.
Change Made       Change Merged
last month        last month
2 months ago      2 months ago
a year ago        yesterday

This makes it very difficult to look at the history of a file and see what recent changes may be causing problems.  What I would like to see instead, is a history that traces the branch and shows changes as they are made to the given branch.
Ideally the output would be ordered as:
Change Made       Change Merged
a year ago        yesterday
last month        last month
2 months ago      2 months ago

I have looked at the history in gitlab, used git log, git extensions, git lens, git log --topo-order.
The concept of --topo-order makes me believe what I want is theoretically possible, but the output of --topo-order wasn't very useful.

Is git log --first-parent what you are looking for?

Add -m, -m  --first-parent, Git's log dumps ordinarily ignore merges when looking for specific changes because people are usually looking for the commits that originated those changes, not the history of where and when they were merged.

If the concept "causing trouble" is readily characterized, it might be simpler to use git bisect.

Maybe --topo-order is what you are looking for. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---topo-order

@kim they already knew that.

@mkrieger1 --first-parent appears to be doing exactly what I was looking for from a task perspective.  I am finding this somewhat cumbersome to work with because it leaves me looking at log outputs and copy/pasting commit hashes in order to see diffs - are there any GUI tools that do this?  Also - I am very grateful for how much further I am thanks to your comment.

If you are looking for a gui tool you probably already have "gitk". It takes mostly the same arguments as git log. (just type gitk in your git bash)
